# Классы в php

Tags: классы, php, сессия

Возможно ли передать в качестве параметра сеанса экземпляр класса?

Answer (score 4):

Экземпляр класса - можно, но он при этом потеряет все методы:
1)

```
$_SESSION['user'] = new User();
```

2)

```
$user = new User();  
$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user); //более правильный способ
```

То есть, сохранится лишь информация о свойствах и хранящаяся в них. Чтобы полностью восстановить объект, используйте **__sleep()**/**__wake()**

Comment: Глупость говорите.

* Никакие методы не могут потеряться, поскольку при десериализации создается экземпляр того-же самого класса. Потеряются только данные, не подлежащие сериализации, например файловые дескрипторы или открытые соединения с БД.

* При сериализации/десериализации методы `__sleep()`/`__wake()` вызываются автоматически. Если они не реализованы, то сериализуются/десериализируются *все* поля класса, в т.ч. и приватные. 

* `$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);` - при сохранении сессия в любом случае сериализируется, т.ч. это бессмысленно.

Comment: По поводу первых двух пунктов соглашусь. По поводу последнего - не совсем. 
Если мы запихнем объект в сессию, а потом вызовем на другой странице, куда НЕ подключен файл с описанием класса, нам радостно выдастся ошибка 

>>__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
>>(
>>    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => User
>>    [public_var] => 1
>>    [protected:protected_var] => 2
>>    [private:User:private_var] => 3
>>)

Что выглядит вполне логично. Собственно об этой "потере" я и написал.

Comment: При этом будет вызван автолоадер с соответствующим именем класса. Т.ч. это не проблема десериализации сессии.

Comment: Будет, если он написан. ;)
Я же не спорю, что если все сделать аккуратно, будет хорошо.

Comment: .

     - Можно ли создать экземпляр класса?
     - Можно, но он не будет иметь никаких методов.
     - Почему?
     - Потому что для этого должен быть подключен файл с описанием класса!

Раз ТС хочет работать с экземпляром класса, то соответствующий класс должен быть объявлен. Это априори. 

А ваш ответ вводит в заблуждение тем, что якобы экземпляры класса, будучи помещенные в сессию, *в обязательном порядке* перестанут быть работоспособными. Уж лучше бы написали про нюанс с `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, можно.
И как коллеги уже написали, необходимо лишь чтобы объявление класса, экземпляр которого передается через сессию, было выполнено раньше session_start. B противном случае десериализация превратит наш объект в экземпляр класса __PHP_Incomplete_Class. 
Но и в данном случае можно поправить ситуацию, пересоздав объект как, например, предлагается вот тут - [Восстанавливаем объект из состояния __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name](http://shra.ru/2014/12/vosstanavlivaem-obekt-iz-sostoyaniya-__php_incomplete_class_name)